# Python deque maxlen does not show

Tags: python, ipython

I have

```py
from collections import deque

dq = deque(range(10), maxlen =  10)
dq

dq.extendleft([10, 20, 30, 40])
dq
```

result

```
deque([40, 30, 20, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

[image]

but in book Fluent Python (2019), I see maxlen, like this

```
deque([40, 30, 20, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], maxlen=10)
```

[image]

Is the different cause by version different?

Comment: What do you mean "I see maxlen"? Does this show in output? Or does the book say to type it in?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: What @wjandrea said. If you typed this in a terminal using the python repl, you would see the output in the book. That's what the book indicates when it shows lines starting with `>>>`. The notebook is showing your the string output, not the result of  `__repr__()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be caused by IPython. If you do `print(dq)` or `print(repr(dq))`, you get your expected output, and same in a normal REPL.

```
In [1]: from collections import deque

In [2]: dq = deque(range(10), maxlen=10)

In [3]: dq
Out[3]: deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [4]: print(dq)
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], maxlen=10)

In [5]: print(repr(dq))
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], maxlen=10)
```

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> dq = deque(range(10), maxlen=10)
>>> dq
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], maxlen=10)
```

---

**Update**: [I've submitted a PR to IPython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/13648) to fix the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest adding (in the ipythoh) a `display(dq)` line.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, what does that show that the plain `Out` line doesn't? I'm not familiar with `display`.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with something in `ipython`, you can do `display?` to learn about it.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, I mean I read the docs but I don't see what the significance is